# Recommendation where to store supporting image or document files for jsfiddle or plunker

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, plunker

Like everyone, I run into issues where the StackOverflow community is great at assisting. Many times, it is easier to "show" the issue via a jsfiddle, plunker, or other online code tool. This works for most scenarios, but in scenarios where I need to reference files such as images or documents that have to be part of the scenario, I am not sure where best to store these for reference.

I was evaluating using my dropbox to allow my code in jsfiddle or plunker to "load" images from, but am unsure if there is a better/more commonplace location to store temporary files for the purposes of troubleshooting by the community.

Where/how do others store their image or document files used in jsfiddle, plunker, etc. that are posted here in StackOverflow? What are the pros/cons?

Comment: Is this supposed to be posted on Meta? You can always upload images by using the “ask a question” or the “answer” form and clicking the image button. Then you can upload an image and copy the URL.

Comment: IIRC, SO uses [imgur](https://imgur.com/). You can use it directly, or follow @Xufox's suggestion.

Comment: This is for jsFiddles or Plunkers I create where I need to use images or files in the examples, not the images I can load into StackOverflow. As an example, for my particular plunk, I need to load files into the same storage directory one file has references to two others that require them to be in the same directory. Some of these are also not files, but XML documents, etc.

Comment: _"where to store supporting image or document files for jsfiddle or plunker"_ Should be able to recreate examples using any image , `html` ; `document.createElement("img")` for images , `<!DOCTYPE html><html></html>` , `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` for documents ; no need "store" image or document ?

Comment: What about a service if I need to store them in the same directory as they have same directory references embedded in an XML file that references them. Would DropBox be the only solution?

Comment: A few of these documents are specific in that I need their content as part of the troubleshooting (ex. XML files with image references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the service that StackOverflow already offers:

- Pretend that you're adding a new image to your question:
  [image]
- Upload the file you want and click on `Add picture`

  [image]
- Then, get the generated image in your question:

  [image]
- And use it inside [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kB0lKwztdQNvGa9d7bNq?p=preview) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

  [image]

You don't need to use the generated image into your question: you can upload it here, and use there.

Comment: Did you guys notice the image inception? :)

Comment: Great guide post. What about non-images, such as PDFs or XML files, including files that need to reside in the same directory (ex. the XML file has references built into it that reference image files). Extreme case, but that might be a good use for the DropBox Public Folder. In most cases this works great!

Comment: XML files can be added manually to Plunker by copying/pasting their contents. And you could replace the XML image references to the uploaded ones, also. But for PDFs, DOCs, etc, then you should be using any of those free services, like Dropbox, Google Drive, Microsoft OneDrive etc.

Comment: Bueno, muy facil!